# Every $v$ in a vector space $V$ can be written uniquely as $v=a_1 v_1+\ldots+a_n v_n$ implies that $V=\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove the statement that $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a basis of $V$ if and only if every $v$ in $V$ can be written uniquely as $v=a_1 v_1+\ldots+a_n v_n$.

I have proven the statement in the first direction but I'm stuck on trying to show that if every $v$ in $V$ can be written uniquely as $v=a_1 v_1+\ldots+a_n v_n$, then $V=\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. My book skips this step in the proof, stating that it is clear. However the only thing that is clear to me from the hypothesis is that $V$ is a subset of $\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$. I don't know how to show that $\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a subset of $V$ so that I can conclude that both are equal.

Comment: span$(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a subset of $V$ because $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is, and $V$ is a vector space (hence closed w.r.t. linear combination of its elements).

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. I think the second part of the statement should have precised that (v_1,...,v_n) were in V.

Comment: Or can we show that (v_1,...,v_n) are elements of V from the hypothesis without explicitely stating it, knowing that every v is an element of a vector space V?

Comment: So, if we're being super formal, the statement should technically say "Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be elements of $V$. Then, $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis iff ..." However, this should be recognized implicitly. If the vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ weren't elements of $V$, what the heck would they be? Generally missing details like this will be clear from context

Comment: Thanks. As a beginner, I think you have to learn when to assume things like this and when not to, because doing either when it is not appropriate will lead to trouble.